# trying to print the contents of a list when using list<class>

Tags: c#, list

I have a class with two variables: Name, Address

I instantiate the class, add values to it, and try to store it in a list. Once I do that I hope to print the Name and Adress on the console but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Address { set; get; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();

        t.Name = "bob";
        t.Address = "CT";

        List<Test> lst = new List<Test>();

        lst.Add(t);

        foreach (var x in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
  }
```

WHen I do this I simply get the name of my project.ClassName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `ToString` in your class. When passed your class-instance to the `Console.WriteLine` function, this `ToString`-function is called.
For further information check the documentation for [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`object.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Address { set; get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {Name} Address: {Address}";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test t = new Test();

    t.Name = "bob";
    t.Address = "CT";

    List<Test> lst = new List<Test>();

    lst.Add(t);

    foreach (var x in lst)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

This will output:

> Name: bob Address: CT

Answer (score 2):

Simply, override `ToString` and everything else should work as you'd expect it to.

Example:

```
class Test
{
     public string Name { set; get; }
     public string Address { set; get; }

     public override string ToString(){
         return $"name: {Name}, address: {Address}";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the Name property inside for loop

```
foreach (var x in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
}
```

Comment: I might have 20 variables in my class and want to be able to print them all at once using a single Console.WriteLine. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No you need forEach to list all the values

Comment: THat's okay, but if I go with your eample I will have to do a seperate Console.WriteLine(x.name), then another Console.WriteLine(x.Address). is there a way to simply print all my variables in one Console.WriteLine(x.whatever), in a single ForEach loop

Comment: You can override the .`ToString()` method on your `class` which you would be able to print out. By default `ToString()` returns the class name of the object.

Comment: modify your class to return the values with ToString)=

Answer (score 1):

for me i will use this

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Test t = new Test();

        t.Name = "bob";
        t.Address = "CT";

        List<Test> lst = new List<Test>();
        lst.Add(t);
        lst.ForEach(show);
    }

    private static void show(Test obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Address);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it print the properties dynamically whenever the class is updated, you can use Json.Net.

```
class Test
{
 public string Name { set; get; }
 public string Address { set; get; }

 public override string ToString()
 {
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
 }

}
```